# Why does remote service lose reference to an object, which holds a reference to a service?

Tags: android, service, process, ibeacon-android

In my case I do communicate with a service from remote process service... In main application I do declare 2 services in manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"/>
<service android:process="my_remote_process" android:name="com.example.ServiceClass"/>
```

Where ever I'd like to, in my case in main activity onCreate() method, I start "Service" which checks SDK version of device and checks is ServiceClass already runing to not duplicate ServiceClass on device. Then I simply start "real" service:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),ServiceClass.class).putExtra("MyExtra", MyExtra));
```

In ServiceClass.java I declare

```
protected BeaconManager beaconManager;
```

as a global variable in the classes scope and I instanciate object in onCreate() method:

```
super.onCreate();
beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
```

and I also have a local custom class called, lets say `public class ManageConnections`
which uses `beaconManager` for establishing connections, scanning regions and etc.

`beaconManager` holds a reference to `BeaconService`, which I declared in manifest.

Now the problem is following:

If I do close the app via "Home" button, BeaconService continues to scan. If I do close the app completely(Do hold "Home" button and swap the activity away) services gets restarted because `ServiceClass` returns `START_STICKY` and BeaconService continues to scan. BUT if I close the app via "Go back" button, after 10-20 Minutes (sometimes even immediatly), my variable `beaconManager`, which was declared in `ServiceClass` classes scope loses reference to `BeaconManager` instance and crashes scanning of `BeaconService`.

What am I missing here? Do I misunderstand processing, threading and services, or does garbage collector destroys the instance? I would say closing the app completely is even worse than just closing it via "Go back" button, but behaviour tells me something different.

Answer (score 0):

Checks is ServiceClass already running to not duplicate ServiceClass on device:
No need to do this, you can only have one instance of a service running in your device if you try to start the service and is already running this method will be call:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;// Restart if killed because of poor resource
}
```

My variable beaconManager, which was declared in ServiceClass classes scope loses reference to BeaconManager instance and crashes scanning of BeaconService.

This happen because Activities and services do not share same Context, each activity have their own context and as soon as the application is remove from the queue de OS release it reference. if what you want is to call your activity once again from the service send your application package and class as a String to the service with putExtra and receive the Extra in onStartCommand.